# Installing pry but ERROR: While executing gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I am trying to install pry on windows using `git` and `bash` but I get this error below. I tried to look everywhere but nothing seems to work. At one point, it was installed successfully, but even after typing the `pry` command, it didn't do anything but gave me a blank page. (it takes a while to give me nothing...)

```
$ gem install pry
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 
(https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/pry-0.10.1-x86-mingw32.gemspec.rz)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**First update your gem:**

> gem update
>
> gem install pry